# Send a echo message from linux TCP client SSH tunneled to linux TCP server in C / C++

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I want to implement a simple echo client/server application which is controlled from the client device. To give it more clarity, I will try to explain my desired scenario as below:

**Host A:**
*eth1:* 192.168.1.1,
*eth2:* 192.168.20.1,
*username: client*,
*password: client_pass*

**Host B:**
*eth1:* 192.168.1.2
*eth2:* 192.168.20.2
*username: server*,
*password: server_pass*

- The application will only run on Host-A.
- Open another TCP connection for receiving "Hello world" i.e. port 55555 on Host B over SSH connection over eth1 interfaces (ssh connection from Host A-eth1 to Host B-eth1, opening a new TCP port on port 55555)
- Send "Hello world" message from Host A-eth2 to Host B-eth2 port 55555.

Since both eth1 and eth2 are committed to different interfaces, no collisions are expected during the transmission.

How can I accomplish with C or C++ program ?

Thanks

Comment: Please could you share any attempts you have made so far?

Comment: I am still trying for days. Most probably, the answer should lay behind <libssh2.h> function with respect to *https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/blob/master/example/tcpip-forward.c*. Pretty complicated to simplify.

Comment: debugging a problem is easiest if only a single objective is processed at a time.  Strongly suggest 1) pick a OS and get that to working before allowing for other OSs.  2) the referenced code does NOT implement the URLs and PORTs that your question references.  3) get one line of communication working, Then get the other line of communication working, then merge the two lines of communication 4) break the code into individual functions, where each function only does one thing.

Comment: Note: port 22 is one of the reserved ports  (0...1024) (and not one of the ports your question is indicting to use.)

Comment: regarding: `sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);`  and the following checking of the returned value.   1) All that really needs to be checked is if the returned value is `>= 0`  2)  I think PF_INET is for communication on the same computer, not across a network

Comment: regarding statements like: `remote_wantport = atoi(argv[5]);`  The function: `atoi()` does not indicate when an error occurs,  Suggest using: `char *endPtr; remote_wantport = strtol(argv[5], &endPtr, 10);`  Then check the character at `**endPtr` must be '\0', other wise some error occurred.  Suggest reading the MAN page for `strtol` for further details

Comment: for statements like: if(forwardsock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open forward socket!\n");
        goto shutdown;`  1) the code at `shutdown:` assumes that a valid socket was created, but that is NOT the case.  The result will (probably) be a seg fault event rather than a clean shutdown

Comment: in the `shutdown` code, it is assumed that `session` contains a valid value, but if anything before the call to `connect()` fails, then `session` contains trash.  The result of calling `libssh2_session_free()` when no valid `session` is ???

Comment: suggest reading/understanding: [libssh2.exec](https://www.libssh2.org/examples/ssh2_exec.html)